# RoR Controller ensure_user_profile implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a RoR app, in which a user can have one or more user profiles.

I need to make a call to a method in a similar way to what it is like `before_action`, something similar to this;

```rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  # I don't know how to implement this
  ensure_user_profile [ :god, :admin, :manager, :supervisor ], only: [ :create ]

end
```

How to implement a `ensure_user_profile` in `ApplicationController` *class* with @current_user *instance* variable?

Comment: Looks like you need a model validation, not a controller callback. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Do you want to automatically create a profile for a user or redirect them to a page so that they can create one?

Comment: Hi @Vasilisa, isn't a validation for model, it's to authorize the HTTP request.

Comment: Hi @ramblex, I want to `raise` a exception and rescue them with redirect.

Comment: It looks like that to me: https://github.com/varvet/pundit